# Intellij how to add call hierarchy to mouse popup menu?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-plugin

Is there a way to add **Call Hierarchy** to mouse popup menu in **Intellij**? I use it a lot and hope it is available on the mouse right click popup menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2018.1.3:

- From the **File** menu select **Settings..**.
- In the left panel select **Appearance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars**.
- In the right panel expand the **Editor Popup Menu** entry.
- Select the final entry of that menu, which (for me) was **JSP Actions**.
- Some buttons on the right should now be enabled. Click the **Add After...** button:

[image: callHierarchy1]

- The **Choose Actions To Add** dialog opens. Navigate to the **Call Hierarchy** entry:

  1. Expand the **Main menu** entry, then expand the **Navigate** entry.
  2. Scroll down and select the **Call Hierarchy** entry.
  3. Click **OK** to close the **Choose Actions To Add** dialog.
- At the end of the list of menu entries there should now be a new entry for **Call Hierarchy**.
- Click **OK** to close the **Settings** window.
- Position the mouse cursor over a method in the editor window, right click and select **Browse Call Hierarchy** from the bottom of the popup menu:

[image: mouseMenu]